# Unable to resolve SonarQube bug for close preparedsStatement

Tags: java, jdbc, sonarqube, prepared-statement

I have a JDBCStreamTemplate class which calls two other methods in classes - JDBCStreamRow and JDBCStreamResultSet. These two classes implements Autoclosable.

JDBCStreamTemplate class methods have connection and preparedStatement. The parameters of sql and connection are passed through a constructor to JDBCStreamRow and JDBCStreamResultSet.

The connection and PresparedStatement are being closed in JDBCStreamRow and JDBCStreamResultSet classes. But the SONARQube is giving bug that Connection and PreparedStatement need to be closed in JDBCStreamTemplate class.

Could you please let me know how to resolve the bug?

I tried to close the PS and CON by putting finally in the JDBCStreamTemplate but it says Statement Closed before any result which is expected.
Below code is of JDBCStreamTemplate class method which calls the JdbcStreamResultSet constructor

```
try {
Connection connection = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(this.getDataSource());
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    preparedStatement.setFetchSize(5000);
    this.newArgPreparedStatementSetter(args).setValues(preparedStatement);
    jdbcStreamResultSet = new JdbcStreamResultSet(qRef, connection, preparedStatement);
} catch (SQLException sqle) {
    logger.error("{} JdbcStreamTemplate::streamResultSet: {}", qRef, JdbcUtilities.formatException(sqle));
    throw sqle;
} catch (CannotGetJdbcConnectionException ce) {
    SQLException sqle = new SQLException(ce.getMostSpecificCause());
    logger.error("{} JdbcStreamTemplate::streamResultSet: {}", qRef, Helpers.getExceptionMessage(sqle));
    throw sqle;
}

    return jdbcStreamResultSet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But the SONARQube is giving bug that Connection and PreparedStatement need to be closed in JDBCStreamTemplate class.

Yes, it is good practice that the code that opens something should also be the one that is responsible for closing it !   Splitting that responsibility up and down the calling tree (ie "creating/opening" in one method, closing in another) makes it difficult to follow the flow of control, and so is asking for trouble.

> The connection and PresparedStatement are being closed in JDBCStreamRow and JDBCStreamResultSet classes.

The other thing is that I do not see anything being "closed" in your code.  You say connection and preparedStatement are being closed in your other classes, but

a) You never close those other classes either, and

b) we don't have the code for those,

SO .......  I'm just going to ignore your other classes, and instead just ensure connection and preparedStatement are closed in this code.

> JDBCStreamRow and JDBCStreamResultSet. These two classes implements Autoclosable.

Both connection and preparedStatement also implement AutoCloseable, so hopefully you should be able to apply the same thinking I'm going to use onto your own classes.

It's important to realise how `Autocloseable` is to be used.  It doesn't mean the JVM makes an arbitrary decision by itself when it's going to close the object.  Instead, all it means is that that object will be closed when used within the "resources" section of the try-with-resources block.

For connection and preparedStatement, that means we can change your code to use try-with-resources so :

```
    try ( Connection connection = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(this.getDataSource());
          PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        )
    { 
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        preparedStatement.setFetchSize(5000);
        this.newArgPreparedStatementSetter(args).setValues(preparedStatement);
        jdbcStreamResultSet = new JdbcStreamResultSet(qRef, connection, preparedStatement);
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        logger.error("{} JdbcStreamTemplate::streamResultSet: {}", qRef, 
            JdbcUtilities.formatException(sqle));
        throw sqle;
    } catch (CannotGetJdbcConnectionException ce) {
        SQLException sqle = new SQLException(ce.getMostSpecificCause());
        logger.error("{} JdbcStreamTemplate::streamResultSet: {}", qRef, Helpers.getExceptionMessage(sqle));
        throw sqle;
    }

    return jdbcStreamResultSet;
}
```

Using this layout, connection and preparedStatement are guaranteed to be closed no matter what happens (and in the right order) - and SONARQube should be happy.